# How can I write a program to install and uninstall an app over android device?

Tags: android

I want to write a program which can install and uninstall an application over android device.As these features are provided over android device,but from where should i start and which files are required to be seen to develop my own application. please help me out.

Thnx in advance.

Praween

Comment: By "Program", do you mean a desktop front end for installing/uninstalling apps on a phone OR a Package Manager INSIDE the phone? Clarify

Answer (score 2):

For installation code like that

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

For uninstall try this.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, Uri.fromParts("package",
    getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(apkUri.getPath(), 0).packageName,null));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Let me know if any issue

Answer (score 0):

In case this is for an independent desktop solution, you can write a simple shell script that executes the following commands. I'm assuming you have the Android SDK installed, as it's required.

To install example.apk located somewhere on your desktop hard drive:

```
cd location_of_sdk\tools
adb.exe install path_to_apk\example.apk
```

---

To uninstall the app:

```
cd location_of_sdk\tools
adb shell
```

Inside the adb shell execute:

```
cd /data/app
ls
```

This will display the apps installed on the device. Look for the .apk associated with the app you want to uninstall. It'll look something like "com.abc.xyz.apk" - then execute:

```
rm com.abc.xyz.apk
exit
```