# How can I write a front end program to install and uninstall an app over android device?

Tags: android

By "Program", I mean a desktop front end for installing/uninstalling apps on a phone.Can u please help me out from this? I am not clear what to do ?

Thnx,
Praween

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I write a program to install and uninstall an app over android device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255075/how-can-i-write-a-program-to-install-and-uninstall-an-app-over-android-device)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First copy your apk file on to your device.suppose you copy your apk fie on download folder on sd card.

```
 String vsName=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/download/";
//your path 
 File file = new File(vsName, "aaa.apk");//put here your apk file      
 System.out.println(":"+file);//checking your path is correct or not   
 Intent install=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");       
 install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
 startActivity(install);
```

for uninstall

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, Uri.fromParts("package",
getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(apkUri.getPath(), 0).packageName,null));
startActivity(intent);
```

Let me comments if any issue.

Comment: Thanx for this ...as I already implemented the same  solution. Thnaks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your original question to clarify ([How can I write a program to install and uninstall an app over android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255075/how-can-i-write-a-program-to-install-and-uninstall-an-app-over-android-device/3260956#3260956)). Anyhow here's my answer again:

You can write a simple shell script that executes the following commands. I'm assuming you have the Android SDK installed, as it's required.

To install example.apk located somewhere on your desktop hard drive:

```
cd location_of_sdk\tools
adb.exe install path_to_apk\example.apk
```

---

To uninstall the app:

```
cd location_of_sdk\tools
adb shell
```

Inside the adb shell execute:

```
cd /data/app
ls
```

This will display the apps installed on the device. Look for the .apk associated with the app you want to uninstall. It'll look something like "com.abc.xyz.apk" - then execute:

```
rm com.abc.xyz.apk
exit
```

Comment: @Andy..But Praween k has asked for the "program"...how it is possible to write in program

Comment: @Paresh Oh, I guess I misread his question. I thought he meant a completely separate program on a computer that can install and uninstall APKs to an attached Android device.

Comment: @Praween..Paresh is right,I want to write an application which can install and unistall the apk file as the packageInstaller does over the device.Thanks Paresh.

Comment: I have this question also. Who can resolve this question? Thank You!